# Smaato Android SDK not working with my publisher id

Tags: java, android, smaato

I am using Smaato's SOMA API for Android (the latest 4.3.0 version).
I am running the included SOMADemo app, but it doesn't work with my publisher id.

Debugging, I saw the code is filled with these:

```
try {
  final String publisherId = sharedPrefs.getString("publisherid", "0");
  mBanner.getAdSettings().setPublisherId(Integer.parseInt(publisherId));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  Log.w("SOMA", "Publisher id has wrong format!");
  mBanner.getAdSettings().setPublisherId(0);
}
```

My publisher id is 92386*****, and thus it fails to convert to a java int (because it is out of range).
But the Smaato SDK expects integer publisher ids everywhere!

Am I missing something? Has anyone come across this before?

Cheers